# only one workspace after upgrade to 13.04

Tags: workspaces, 13.04

Title says it all.

Where can I add workspaces - looked into CompizConfig but I was not able to find a tab where I can specify the # of workspaces. I used to have 2X2 and that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to System Settings > Appearance > Behavior Tab > Enable Workspaces