# How to change desktop workspace?

Tags: 13.04, workspaces, workspace-switcher

In version 12.10 we could change spaces with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd>/<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>. But now?
Are there spaces here?

No information keeping pressed the super key.

Comment: In 13.04 viewports are switched OFF by defaults so the shortcut is also disabled. See "appearances". http://askubuntu.com/questions/285635/only-one-workspace-after-upgrade-to-13-04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System settings` -> `Appearance` -> `Behavior` -> `Enable workspaces checkbox`. Works for me